# Spotting and condensing expressions in output

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

I am running some symbolic scripts to generate a model problem. One of my outputs is

[image]

This is generated by the Mathematica code

[image]

or, in Mathematica format (owing to the fancy lettering and formatting used)

```
Subscript[
    \!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalB]\), \(_\)]\), 
      i] = {0, 0, 
        Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalB], 
         z][\[ScriptX], \[ScriptY], \[ScriptT]]} + 
       Curl[{0, 
         0, \[ScriptCapitalA][\[ScriptX], \[ScriptY], \[ScriptT]]}, {\
    \[ScriptX], \[ScriptY], \[ScriptZ]}];
    Subscript[
    \!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalB]\), \(_\)]\), 
      a] = {Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalB], a][\[ScriptT]] Cos[\[Phi]], 
       Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalB], a][\[ScriptT]] Sin[\[Phi]], 0};
    
    \!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalB]\), \(_\)]\) = Subscript[
    \!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalB]\), \(_\)]\), a] + Subscript[
    \!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalB]\), \(_\)]\), i];
    Subscript[
    \!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[ScriptR]\), \(_\)]\), 
      w] = {Subscript[\[ScriptX], w][\[ScriptS]], 
       Subscript[\[ScriptY], w][\[ScriptS]], \[ScriptZ]}; 
    VectorNorm[vec_] := Sqrt[vec . vec];
    UnitVector2[vec_] := vec/VectorNorm[vec];
    UnitTangent[vec_, param_] := UnitVector2[D[vec, param]]
    UnitNormal[vec_, param1_, param2_] := 
      UnitVector2[D[vec, param1]\[Cross]D[vec, param2]] ;
    NormalNorm[vec_, param1_, param2_] := 
      VectorNorm[(D[vec, param1]\[Cross]D[vec, param2])];
    Subscript[
    \!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[ScriptN]\), \(_\)]\), w] = 
      FullSimplify[UnitNormal[Subscript[
    \!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[ScriptR]\), \(_\)]\), 
        w], \[ScriptZ], \[ScriptS]]];
    magFieldNormalWall =  FullSimplify[
    \!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalB]\), \(_\)]\) . Subscript[
    \!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[ScriptN]\), \(_\)]\), w]]
```

However, it is often more convenient to write the final two terms as

$$ \dfrac{\partial A}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x_{w}}{\partial s}+\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y_{w}}{\partial s}=\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial s}
$$

but I don't know how to make Mathematica think "this expression looks like the above so let's write it as that". Is there an easy way to get Mathematica to "reverse simplify" an expression by condensing it into a more convenient form?

Comment: Please include Mathematica code for this expression so that someone is able to help you further. Thanks.

Comment: Please include copy-paste-able code, not its picture. You can copy directly from the input cell and paste in the `Edit` window where there is a  braces button `{  }` to help you format it. Thanks.

Comment: Prior to copy and paste convert cells to `Raw InputForm` or at least `InputForm`

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Answer (score 1):

Does this help:

[image]

??

The body must be at least 30 symbols, therefore, I add this senseless text.

Comment: Instead of the senseless test, please explain what changes you have made to the code, and post text, not pictures.

Comment: @MarcoB I am intentionally posting the image, rather than a code, since OP made his code with a huge number of sub-, superscripts, and script font. These make it absolutely impossible to view the code and the output, let alone to understand it. Like I did, one can see and understand what has been done. As for the explanation, I applied a simple rule. It is exactly the one OP wants. I only left one item in the left-hand part and placed the rest into the right-hand part.